# How can i make a New intent for a button to open a new Class?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

Here is My Code,I need a  to put something inside{} to link the button to new class or activity like second page.java :

```
public void addListenerOnButton() {

        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


/*What can I put here to open new class 
,I mean another activity like secondp.java.*/



            }
```

I Tried to put below code, but I got the following error:

```
The constructor Intent(new View.OnClickListener(){}, Class<List>) is undefined
```

**Code**

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent k = new Intent(this,Secondp.class);
                startActivity(k);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Simple

You're using the wrong `this` :)
`this` would pass in the `OnClickListener` class to the Intent when a context is required.

**Use:**

```
startActivity(new Intent(NameofyourcurrentActivity.this,Second.class));
```

Comment: `this`, in this case, passes off the Listener, not the View. Also, `arg0`,a [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) does not have a `getApplicationContext()` method, but it does have `getContext()`.

Comment: @A--C is it the same context as getApplicationContext?

Comment: Should be the Context that the Button is defined in, so the Activity context. However, what it is is irrelevant for starting an Activity this way - all Contexts can start Activities and intents just need a Context passed.

Comment: @DheeB   Thank you so much ,it just worked. The previous answers didn't work.

Comment: @– A--C  I worked a little on them and finally both worked.Thanx

Comment: @– A--C I mean they all work but the simpler the code better it works; while translating into c# or when I use by codenameone. I mean:startActivity(new Intent(NameofyourcurrentActivity.this,Second.class)); same but better than Intent k = new Intent(arg0.getContext(),Secondp.class);
   startActivity(k); or other while translating.The last one just worked.Thanx to Dheeb for writing and you for editing I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Intent k = new Intent(this,Secondp.class);
```

to

```
Intent k = new Intent(NameofyourcurrentActivity.this,Secondp.class);
```

Using just `this` keyword, you are passing the object of `OnClickListener`

Answer (score 0):

try removing the "this" clause, cause when you use the "this" in your code, it is referring to the onclicklistener class. if you wants to add in the context, make an reference of your context before the methods and use that instead.